# Windows 8 Metro apps Sqlite Issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro

I created an example on C# with Sqlite database, following this example:

[using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/)

It works properly on my development machine, creating database and add entries, but when I am using this example or app on client machine it never create database.
I don't know what happens to it.

You can use this example for test. It is also work the same as mine.

[example](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/SqlLiteTest.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.
I created package in Debugging Mode this is wrong way, it must be created in Release Mode.